# How to run Angular application in kiosk mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am making an online test portal where I want the candidate should not reload or move to another tab during the test. So I was thinking rather than disabling the browser functionalities is there any way programmatically to run the app in Kiosk mode?
It will be helpful if any other suggestion other than this can make the application better.

Comment: Considering angular is just a script running on a client, your best bet would be to use any kind of kiosk-software that allows for JS to be embedded or maybe a PWA. Angular it self will not be able to fully implement what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be up to the browser, not your app to disable these features, you can launch browsers like chromium from the command line and pass the kiosk flag, so you could just update your node start script to launch to a browser that is set for kiosk mode.

Comment: @GarrettManley while specifying ```kiosk``` flag do I need to mention ```localhost:port_number``` ?

Comment: one more thing - currently my app has only the test screen to open in full-screen mode. So is there any way that I can disable the page reload, new tab/window opening, can't exit full screen mode ?

Comment: If you're trying to use chrome, you can just run chrome from the command line and pass the flag `--kiosk` and the next argument you pass is the `localhost:port` that your application is running on.